# Adding buttons for previous and next slide in Vegas slider

Tags: javascript, vegasjs

I have very simple slider created with Vegas Slideshow. Now I'm trying to add simple Prev/Next buttons. This is the slider

```
    <div class="slide-caption"></div>


    <script src="/assets/js/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/vegas.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(".slider-wrapper").vegas({
            slides: [
                { src: "/assets/images/slide-1.jpg", text: "Deployment" },
                { src: "/assets/images/slide-1.jpg", text: "Deployment" },
            ],
            walk: function (index, slideSettings) {
                $('.slide-caption').html(slideSettings.text);
            }
        });
    </script>
```

This works perfectly. It is showing the image and the caption bellow.

Now I've tried to add this for the buttons but nothing is appeared on page. There is no errors in console. I'm not sure also if I need to add the HTML for the buttons or it is pull them from the JS and CSS of the Vegas

```
    <script>
        $(".slider-wrapper").vegas({
            slides: [
                { src: "/assets/images/slide-1.jpg", text: "Deployment" },
                { src: "/assets/images/slide-1.jpg", text: "Deployment" },
            ],
            walk: function (index, slideSettings) {
                $('.slide-caption').html(slideSettings.text);
            }
        });

         // buttons
        $('a#previous').on('click', function () {
        $elmt.vegas('options', 'transition', 'slideRight2').vegas('previous');
        });

        $('a#next').on('click', function () {
            $elmt.vegas('options', 'transition', 'slideLeft2').vegas('next');
        });
    </script>
```

Anyone know how exactly I can add the buttons?

Comment: You may be able to skip the link element and simply create a div element for the buttons...

    <div id="previous"></div>

With jquery selector switching from

    $('a#previous).on to $('#previous').click

Comment: @KevMoe can you show me.. Seems I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but it may get you heading in the right direction...

```
HTML...
<div id="previous" class="button"></div>
<div id="next" class="button"></div>


JQUERY...
    <script>
    $("#previous").click( function() {
$elmt.vegas('options', 'transition', 'slideRight2').vegas('previous');
});

$("#next").click( function() {
$elmt.vegas('options', 'transition', 'slideRight2').vegas('next');
});

</script>       
CSS...
.button {
display: block;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
background-color: purple;
 }
```

Comment: I see only the the next button and this error in the console `ReferenceError: $elmt is not defined`

Comment: I'm not familiar with vegasjs... it looks to me like it needs to be defined on that document.